# Проблема с контроллерами в Spring-MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Здравствуйте, в последних нескольких коммитаъ возникла странная ошибка, так и не получилоьс отследить откуда у нее корни растут, хотя до этого все работало прекрасно, вот пример кода:

#### Controller

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/auethentification")
public class AuethentificationController {

    @Autowired
    private Auethentification auethentification;
    @Autowired
    private Olympiad olympiad;

    // ...

    @RequestMapping(value = "/logIn", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
    public @ResponseBody String logIn(@RequestParam(value = "login_sign_in") String login,
                                  @RequestParam(value = "pass_sign_in") String password) {
        RoleUser roleUser = auethentification.authenticate(login, password);
        switch (roleUser) {
            case ADMIN:
                return "admin_room";
            case USER:
                olympiad.startOlympiad(login, password);
                return "tasks";
            case UNKNOWN:
                return "Не правильные данные";
        }
        return "Не правильные данные";
    }

    // ...

}
```

#### JSP

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value="/auethentification/logIn"/>" class="sign-in-htm">
    <div class="group">
        <label class="label">Логин</label>
        <input name="login_sign_in" type="text" class="input">
    </div>
    <div class="group">
        <label class="label">Пароль</label>
        <input name="pass_sign_in" type="password" class="input" data-type="password">
    </div>
        <div class="group">
        <button name="btn_sign_in" class="button btn">Войти</button>
    </div>
    <p class="log_in animated" data-effect="tada"></p>
</form><!-- end sign-in-html -->
```

#### JS

```
formSignIn.submit(function(){
    disableButton(btnSignIn);
    var login = $("input[name='login_sign_in']");
    var password = $("input[name='pass_sign_in']");
    if(login.val() === ""){
        loggerSignIn.html("Не введен логин.");
        animate(loggerSignIn);
        enableButton(btnSignIn);
        return false;
    }
    if(password.val() === ""){
        loggerSignIn.html("Не введен пароль.");
        animate(loggerSignIn);
        enableButton(btnSignIn);
        return false;
    }
    authenticate(formSignIn, btnSignIn);
});

function authenticate(form, btn){
    disableButton(btn);
    $.post(form.attr("action"), form.serialize(), function(response){
        switch (response){
            case "tasks" :
                $(location).attr("href", "/tasks/showPage");
                break;
            case "admin_room" :
                $(location).attr("href", "/adminRoom/showPage");
                break;
            default :
                // ...
        }
    });
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

#### Configuration

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.testingsystem.controllers")
public class MVCConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver setupViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        resolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        return resolver;
    }

    // ...

}
```

#### Ошибка

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod  - Failed to resolve argument 0 of type 'java.lang.String'
org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'login_sign_in' is not present
// ...
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ru.testingsystem.controllers.AuethentificationController.logIn(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'login_sign_in' is not present
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.ResponseStatusExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ru.testingsystem.controllers.AuethentificationController.logIn(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'login_sign_in' is not present
[http-nio-8080-exec-4] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String ru.testingsystem.controllers.AuethentificationController.logIn(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)]: org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException: Required String parameter 'login_sign_in' is not present
```

И вот дело в том что на всех контроллерах такая ерунда, хотя просто на выдачу страницы все отлично работает, но как тольок окнтроллер принимает данные, то... Надеюсь что кто-нибудь подскажет в чем дело, то уже просто не знаю что делать.

Comment: Попробуйте немного локализовать проблему. Откройте developer tools в браузере и посмотрите конкретный запрос, который уходит, при нажатии на клавишу. Там будет хотя бы видно где ошибка - на бэке или фронте.

Comment: Получилось получше покапаться и выявил, что у тех контроллеров которые используют метод POST возникает эта проблема, а с методом GET все работает, правда почему??? Не могу понять...

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в аннотировании параметров аннотацией @RequestParam. Параметры, помеченные данные аннотацией будут искаться в параметрах запроса. Т.е. если запрос будет вида POST /auethentification/logIn?login_sign_in="login"&pass_sign_in="password", то у Вас скорее всего все сработает. В случае POST запроса данные формы будут в теле запроса, поэтому Вам можно объединить Ваши параметры в класс, например LoginForm и принимать в методе этот класс

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logIn", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public @ResponseBody String logIn(@RequestBody LoginForm form) {
    RoleUser roleUser = auethentification.authenticate(form.login, form.password);
    switch (roleUser) {
        case ADMIN:
            return "admin_room";
        case USER:
            olympiad.startOlympiad(form.login, form.password);
            return "tasks";
        case UNKNOWN:
            return "Не правильные данные";
    }
    return "Не правильные данные";
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за совет, я завтра попробую, но а почему же раньше все работало?

Comment: Получается придется для каждой формы создавать класс?

Comment: Можно просто использовать Map<String, Object> вместо собственного класса